# How to simplify var() of one variable based on a condition in another variable in r

Tags: r, apply, lapply, var

The following code calculates the variance of variable 7, based on the condition in variable 1.

```
var(df[df$var1=="a",7])
var(df[df$var1=="b",7])
```

How can I simplify it? Does apply make sense?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `sapply(c('a', 'b'), function(x) var(df[df$var1==x,7]))`.

Comment: sorry about being too unspecific. The result should be two variances, one for all cases "a" in variable1 and one for all cases "b" in variable1. Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Thank you Abdou! Your code works perfectly :)

Comment: @JensStach, feel free to accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to get the desired output:

```
sapply(c('a', 'b'), function(x) var(df[df$var1==x,7]))
```

I hope this helps.